# Can i create a round canvas in javafx?

Tags: canvas, javafx, fxml

I was wondering if it was possible to make a javafx canvas have a round shape. A classic canvas is a rectangle, can i change that ? 
Thanks guys! 
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

You cannot truely make the canvas round. You could prevent anything outside a circular area from being rendered though.

This can be done by setting the `clip` property of the `Canvas`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final double size = 400;
    final double radius = size / 2;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(size, size);

    canvas.setClip(new Circle(radius, radius, radius));

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // draw something
    final double padding = 25;
    gc.fillRect(padding, padding, size - padding * 2, size - padding * 2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(canvas)));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

or you clip the drawn content using the path and `GraphicsContext.clip`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    final double size = 400;
    final double radius = size / 2;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(size, size);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    // create path for circle
    gc.beginPath();
    gc.arc(radius, radius, radius, radius, 0, 360);
    gc.closePath();

    // apply path as clip
    gc.clip();

    // draw something
    final double padding = 25;
    gc.fillRect(padding, padding, size - padding * 2, size - padding * 2);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(canvas)));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```